# Book about teenage girl in the desert during a flash flood. She was either a vampire or vampire hunter

Tags: story-identification, books, vampire

Looking for a book I read as a teen in the 90’s about a teenage girl who may(?) have been a vampire or vampire hunter who was in the desert during a flash flood. There was also a lot of talk about her letterman? jacket. I believe it was part of a series and the girl had blonde hair. Wasn’t Buffy.